# If I were to write "two people like each other but not a third person" in first order logic, would I have to specify x, y, z are not the same person?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

If I were to write "two people like each other but not a third person" in first order logic, would I have to specify x, y, z are not the same person?

I would attempt to write it as (using correct notation unlike here):

There exists x, y, z(Likes(X,Y) and Likes(Y,X) implies There exists z(notLikes(X,Z) and notLikes(Y,Z))

Would I also have to add the following onto the end, before the last bracket:

and notEquals(x,y) and notEquals(x,z) and notEquals(y,z)

Do we ever use the "is element of" notation in first order logic? I don't think I have seen it.

Furthermore, in first order logic, we often use a superscript letter m to denote that the function is under interpretation m. If an exam question were to give me a first order structure, when translating an english sentence, would I keep the superscript "m" on all relations?

Comment: Well, if you wish to exclude the cases in which $x$ likes themselves but not some third person then you must exclude that case.

Comment: In other words, using different symbols, X, Y doesn't imply that X and Y are not equal in first order logic?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, no.

Comment: It only means that they're not *necessarily* equal. In mathematics we want to be able to say things like "for all real numbers $x, y$ we have $x + y = y + x$" without excluding the special case $x = y$ which there's usually no reason to exclude.

Comment: "Two people like each other but not a third person" is ambiguous.

There's no 3rd party that they both like (but they can separately like different 3rd parties)?

Neither likes anyone else?

Neither likes a particular 3rd party?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the main connective be AND rather than IMPLIES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, writing $\exists x\exists y(...)$ means iterating over ALL possible values of $x$ and $y$, including the special case in which $x=y$. If you want to exclude this special case, then you have to state this EXPLICITLY in the predicate.

E.g. if you want to say that a predicate is true for at least two (different) elements of the universe, you would write:

$\exists x\exists y(x\not=y \land P(x) \land P(y))$

As you can see, we have to state explicitly that $x$ has to be different from $y$, otherwise the expression would be true even if the predicate was only true for one single element of the universe.

The "is element of", or rather $\in$, notation is practically a function that takes two objects and returns a true/false value, so of course it can be used in first-order logic. One example would be when expressing the equality of two sets in first-order logic. Two sets A and B are equal, if and only if:

$\forall x(x\in A\iff x\in B)$

I am not quite sure what you are refering to when mentioning the "superscript m". Maybe you could give us an example?